# unable to remove tomcat jdbc dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pom.xml, hikaricp, tomcat-jdbc

I am building a spring-boot application using an alternative to tomcat related stuff (jetty instead of tomcat and hikariCP instead of tomcat-jdbc) and want to exclude them from my dependencies written in pom.xml

I did that for 2 of the packages as shown below -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But there is some dependency which is including tomcat-jdbc as part of it.

Is there a way to debug that and find out which dependency is including tomcat jdbc as part of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

If you run mvn dependency:tree, you will see that there are now a number of additional dependencies.